# Font Awesome Blank rectangles

Tags: font-awesome

I have linked it correctly adding "http:" before the link since I am using a localHost

```
<head runat="server">
<title>Brave Watches</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link href ="CSS/bootstrap.min.css" rel ="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href ="CSS/custom.css" rel ="stylesheet" />

<link href ="JavaScript/Custom.js" rel="" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Cartfiles/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Cartfiles/assets/css/custom.css"/> 
<head/>
```

And I have added fa before fa-"icon"

```
<div class ="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
        </div>
```

Still don't understand why it is giving me the blank rectangles. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to be working fine when I import the URL you're using as a resource in a JS Fiddle, and then paste in your HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/degoeym/3fr65dcm/1/

Comment: I still see the blank rectangles in JSFiddle, is my hardware the problem, am I missing a plug in?

Comment: Possibly, but you're pulling them in via the CDN, so it shouldn't matter what you do or don't have on your system. I'd say test things on another device if you can to see if you run into the same issue. Barring knowing what you're developing in, I'm not sure there's much more help to be offered.

Comment: Hmm on my school computer it works fine with all the icons being displayed but on my personal computer it has this problem... Considering I do most of my work at home this is a big problem...